# How to filter an array from all elements of another array in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 array array1 is:

```
arrayFirst=[{id: 417, tseAccountId: 21997, isin: 'IRO3ASKZ0001', totalBuyQuantity:300000,totalSellQuantity:2000}
{id: 418, tseAccountId: 21997,  isin: 'IRO7MFMP0001',totalBuyQuantity:300000,totalSellQuantity:2000}
{id: 419, tseAccountId: 21997,  isin: 'IRT1CSNF0001',totalBuyQuantity:1000,totalSellQuantity:0}
{id: 420, tseAccountId: 21997,  isin: 'IRO1BSDR0001',totalBuyQuantity:1000,totalSellQuantity:0}
{id: 423, tseAccountId: 21997, isin: 'IRO1BMLT0001',totalBuyQuantity:300000,totalSellQuantity:0}]
```

and array2 is :

```
   arraySecond =[{title: 'totalBuyQuantity', value: 300000}
{title: 'totalSellQuantity', value: 20000}
{title: 'isin', value: 'IRO3ASKZ0001'}]
```

I want to filter the first array so that it has all the fields in the second array The result I expect is:

```
result:[{id: 417, tseAccountId: 21997, isin: 'IRO3ASKZ0001', totalBuyQuantity:300000,totalSellQuantity:2000}]
```

Comment: Are you looking to fliter the array with the same total buy and sell quantity?

Comment: Yes and of course isin

Comment: Suppose array2 is: `[{title: 'tseAccountId', value: 21997}, {title: 'totalBuyQuantity', value:300000}];` what should the result be?

Comment: result be :`[{id: 419, tseAccountId: 21997,  isin: 'IRT1CSNF0001',totalBuyQuantity:1000,totalSellQuantity:0}
{id: 420, tseAccountId: 21997,  isin: 'IRO1BSDR0001',totalBuyQuantity:1000,totalSellQuantity:0}]`

Comment: Please try this: `console.log(arrayFirst.filter((elt) => arraySecond.every(({ title, value }) => elt?.[title] === value )));` and share your feedback. Basically, filter array-1 to keep only those element/s which have every prop matching in array-2.

Comment: @jsN00b
Thank you very much, this was the answer I wanted